# Highcharts access angular component value inside formatter function

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have the following formatter function within Angular application:

```
dataLabels: [{
          enabled: true,
          formatter: function () {
            return Math.round(this.point.y * 10000) / 100 + "%";
          }]
```

I would like to access Angular component level property in the formatter function. I can do this by using `.bind(this)` however `this.point.y` is no longer accessible after binding.

```
dataLabels: [{
          enabled: true,
          formatter: function () {
            return Math.round(this.point.y * 10000) / 100 + "%"; //// This does not work. 
          }.bind(this)]
```

How can I access value of point y after binding to this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using bind on the formatter, maybe there is another way to get to it?

Comment: I am trying to access a component level property. It is accessible after binding to "this" using this.componentLevelProperty inside the formatter function. There is a conditional login inside the formatter function using this.componentLevelProperty. The componentLevelProperty determines either to format as % or $ or no formatting.

Comment: I was facing similar issue with yAxis.labels.formatter function but I managed to access the value using parameter.  Ex: function (data:any) { data.value }.bind(this)

Comment: Thanks for explaining,  [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ca8ydb1p/). Have you try to get to property via 'chart.events load()'? There should be more options available for the chart, because it has already been created before and after that dataLabels are rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I would like to access the property in the formatter function. Not sure how charts.events load will help. Do you have a working example to show it working?

Comment: I checked [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-4dfehg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) it looks like can't get to the formatter inside chart.events.load, I will try to do with update method.

Comment: Could you be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To access this.componentLevelProperty you can use a scope that gives arrow function.

```
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: () => {
      console.log(this.somePropertyOnTheAppComponent);

      return 'update';
    },
  },
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-s6yjoq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if I convert it to arrow function then I am not able to access this.point.y value. I would like to access both this.somePropertyOnTheAppComponent and this.point.y values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it.
I have a variable

```
@Input currency:string;
```

So I want to prepend currency in the X-axis value along with some number formating.

So I stored current this in `_self` and accessed currency inside the formatter function using `_self.currency`, as shown below:

```js
    const _self = this;

    this.chartOptions = {
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function x() {
          const formattedX = Highcharts.numberFormat(this.x, -1);
          const formattedY = Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, -1);
          const xAxisTitle = this.series.xAxis.options.title.text;
          const yAxisTitle = this.series.yAxis.options.title.text;

          const xWithCurrency = _self.currency + formattedX;

          return `<div class="dataviz__tooltip">
    <div class="dataviz__tooltip-header">${xAxisTitle}: ${xWithCurrency}</div>
    <div class="dataviz__tooltip-value"style="color: #26C0C7;">${yAxisTitle}: ${formattedY}</div>
    </div>`;
        },
      },
```